# How to pronounce SCImago?

Tags: language, scopus

My mother language is not English and I am not sure how I should pronounce in fron of my students the word "SCImago" for journal & country rank by Scopus at https://www.scimagojr.com.

Comment: My mother language is English, and I _also_ don't know how to pronounce "Scimago", because it's not an English word.  But I would probably guess "Ski-mah-go".

Comment: Perhaps ask on English.se

Comment: Any updates on this? There are various pronunciations doing the rounds, including:
1) 'SKIM-ago'; (skim as in skim milk) 
2) 'skI-mAgo'; (ski as in snow ski)
3) 'sci-mAgo'; (sci as in science)
4) others...

Answer (score 2):

**Just ask SCImage how to pronounce their name.** There's a contact email in their [About Us](https://www.scimagojr.com/aboutus.php) page.

In the mean time, just choose whatever pronunciation you like, and tell your students you're not sure what the right pronunciation is.

Myself, I would say it's "sci" like in science + "imago" with a hard g (like in "egg") - and extend the i as though it's doubled. So kind of like "scyimaggo".

Comment: I think your suggestion would be more correct if it had two “I”s; as it is, I’d probably just use one I sound- and since the SCI is capitalized, i would think that it’d take precedence.